# Web application not found src/main/webapp

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty

I am currently using intellij for my java code. When i try to run the Project, it throws the below error.

```
2016-06-21 09:19:46.691::INFO:  jetty-6.1.14
2016-06-21 09:19:46.843::WARN:  Web application not found src/main/webapp
2016-06-21 09:19:46.843::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@359d136a{/admin,src/main/webapp}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/webapp
```

Comment: error code in block, removed thanks

Comment: Jetty 6 was EOL (End of Life) back in 2010.  Consider upgrading.

Comment: `src/main/webapp` is part of the maven standard conventions. Are you working with maven? Is there a file named `pom.xml`in your project directory?

Comment: yes i am using maven and i have pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

In RUN >> Edit Configurations, Working directory $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kNEZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the folder "webapp" to your classpath/resources-folder?

I guess you have something like:

```
applicationContext.setBaseResource(Resource.newClassPathResource("webapp", true, true));
```

In your WebAppContext-configuration - so, just add a folder named "webapp" under "src/main/resources/." and I guess it should be working as intended.

Comment: I do have a folder named web app. The stucture is as below. Src/main/webapp

Comment: He's using Jetty 6.  `WebAppContext.setBaseResource()` was likely not available back then, it was still on the `setResourceBase()` technique (which uses `Strings`, not `Resource`s)